# Nested floats clearfix stretches to wrong height explanation

Tags: html, css, css-float, clearfix

I have an issue with floated divs and the clearfix on them. The clearfix makes the container expand to the wrong height. In the JSfiddle html part, I have added `<!-- ADD class="container" HERE -->` . Add the class to the div it's next to and you'll see its childs (h_container) expanding.

http://jsfiddle.net/f9ojod2y/1/

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right_f">
    </div>
    <div class="left_f">
        <div>    <!-- ADD class="container" HERE -->
           <div class="h_container">
                <div class="left_h">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="h_container">
               <div class="right_h">

               </div> 
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is right_f floated right. h_container is floated left

I expected `h_container` would not expand at all, but it expands to the height of `right_f`. I know the issue is solvable by deleting `display:table` from the clearflix or by removing the class, but for certain reasons I want the class to be there.

Can anyone explain why clearfix inside `left_f` makes `h_container` the same height as `right_f`?

Also, I noticed that in the jsfiddle there is free space above the green div which i can't explain. It is not there in my original code.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me, hope it will resolve your issue.

**Change these classes:**

```
.right_f {
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
.left_f {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 220px);
}
```

just add one class to remove extra padding coming due to `<p>` tag:

```
.container p{
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
}
```

**Please let me know if this works, also specify which 3 divs you want same height, I can suggest code for that too. Thanks**

Comment: If i add this to the JSfiddle I provided, it does not solve the text from jumping down. (neither does removing the <p> tags)

Comment: Please find the updated answer above, let me know what other issue remaining.

Comment: This does solve it(+1), but does not give an explanation(which I searched for) why the clearfix has this behaviour: ('sometext sometext ...) in the JSfiddle jumping down when adding class="container"

Comment: clear:both; property has been applied to .container:after & container:before. If you edit the class

container:after,
container:before{clear:both}
and remove Container:after from it, it will work 

<b>Reason:</b>

What clearfix do: 
A clearfix is a way for an element to automatically clear its child elements which has a float property in its class, so that you don't need to add additional markup.

Clear:both clear any floats in child's div element, so that the parent element will not collapse.

Comment: I know what it does. But a) I suspect after a clearfix the parent would get it's child's height, however in this case it doesn't do that.  It gets the height of the red div instead of the yellow/cyan one. The red div is not the divs child! B) the problem is not only container after : clear:both that causes it, also display:table fixes it